# Display Crosstab Correctly in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to display a simple crosstab in my Shiny app, but the `renderTable` function seems to reformat the table. How do I construct the table in `renderTable`, or is there another way to display my original table?

```
purchase_by_sex = table(sales$purch_freq, sales$sex)
```

This gets me the desired output in the console;

```
                     Female Male
  Once a Week           3    9
  Once a Month          7   11
  Every 2-3 Months      6    8
  < Every 3 Months      5    2
  Never                20   15
  Don't Know            6    8
```

but gets reformatted in Shiny;

```
Var1                Var2     Freq
Once a Week         Female    3
Once a Month        Female    7
Every 2-3 Months    Female    6
< Every 3 Months    Female    5
Never               Female    20

ui <- fluidPage( tableOutput("table2") )

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$table2 <- renderTable(purchase_by_sex, striped=TRUE, bordered = TRUE)}
```

Answer (score 4):

`renderTable()` expects as input a `data.frame`, which the result of `table(sales$purch_freq, sales$sex)` is not. Try:

```
class(table(sales$purch_freq, sales$sex))
```

that returns:

```
[1] "table".
```

I think `renderTable` thus parses the table to a `data.frame` itself, and indeed we can see that `as.data.frame(purchase_by_sex)` creates your undesired output:

```
       Var1   Var2 Freq
1     often female    2
2    rarely female    5
3 sometimes female    1
4     often   male    6
5    rarely   male    4
6 sometimes   male    2
```

You can use the `as.data.frame.matrix(purchase_by_sex)` function to convert the table into a `data.frame` object with the right layout:

```
          female male
often          2    6
rarely         5    4
sometimes      1    2
```

and then all we have to do is set `rownames=True` in `renderTable`. Hope this helps!

---

Working example:

```
library(shiny)

sales = data.frame(sex=sample(c('male','female'),20,TRUE),purch_freq=sample(c('sometimes','often','rarely'),20,TRUE))

purchase_by_sex = table(sales$purch_freq, sales$sex)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("table2"),
  tableOutput("table3")

)

# create the server
server <- function( input, output, session ){
  output$table2 <- renderTable( purchase_by_sex, striped=TRUE, bordered = TRUE)
  output$table3 <- renderTable( as.data.frame.matrix(purchase_by_sex), striped=TRUE, bordered = TRUE,rownames = T)

  }


shiny::shinyApp( ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

[image]